# Segregate the Handled errors from json Deserialization via Newtonsoft c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm Handling the errors while deserializing json using NewtonSoft and storing the errors in a list as shown in [Newtonsoft Error handling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm)

The problem is that all the errors received ie. even if its "parsing error" or "required member missing error" are of type JsonSerializationException, I'm not able to segregate the errors by type(I Don't wanna do it via string operations like contains on the message).

Are there any other approaches or library available that I can use for this purpose ie. getting a list of segregated errors in json deserializing?

Comment: You could take a look at the [`InnerException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Exception_InnerException) property of the `JsonSerializationException`, maybe they'll be of different type sou you can *sort/ separate* them by that. But what do you want to do with the separated exceptions anyways?

Comment: innerException is null. There are multiple fields... Segregation would allow generalizing the errors like "missing fields: field1, field2, field3"

Comment: If you want to display nice and fancy error messages, you should look at [validating JSON with JSON schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) as well as [generating JSON schemas](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GeneratingSchemas.htm) that Newtonsoft.Json (a.k.a Json.NET) provides

Answer (score 0):

You can start from something like this:

```
        string json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
        var schemaGenerator = new JSchemaGenerator();
        var schema = schemaGenerator.Generate(typeof(List<Product>));
        var jToken = JToken.Parse(json);
        JsonValidationErrorSegregation errors = new JsonValidationErrorSegregation();

        jToken.Validate(schema, (sender, eventArgs) => {
            if (eventArgs.ValidationError.ErrorType == ErrorType.Required)
            {
                errors.RequiredErrors.Add(eventArgs.Message);
            }
            else if (eventArgs.ValidationError.ErrorType == ErrorType.Type)
            {
                errors.InvalidTypeErrors.Add(eventArgs.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Unhandled Error Type");
            }
        });
```

Happy coding, cheers!

Comment: its a good way. But, Schema generation and then validation creates a lot of extra load in code. I'd prefer a better way... That's why I was avoiding JSchema. Further, JSchema is not totally free.